# User balance from a transaction table

Tags: orm, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, doctrine

I am interested to know the best way to monitor a users balance in a transactions table where a transaction is either a deposit or a withdraw.

My current table structure is:

```
private $id;
private $user;
private $type; //credit or debit
private $identity; //deposit, transfer, withdraw
private $amount;
private $description;
private $scoredFee; //fixed charge
private $commission; //% charge
private $method; //cc, wallet etc.
private $status;
```

To work out a users balance I simply take the sum of all credits and subtract the sum of all debits:

```
public function getUserBalance(User $userObject)
{
    $credits = $this->transactionRepository->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->add('select','SUM(u.amount)')
        ->where('u.status = :status')
        ->andWhere('u.type = :type')
        ->andWhere('u.user = :userObject')
        ->setParameter('status' , 1)
        ->setParameter('type' , 1)
        ->setParameter('userObject' , $userObject)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getSingleScalarResult();

    $debits = $this->transactionRepository->createQueryBuilder('u')
        ->add('select','SUM(u.amount)')
        ->where('u.status = :status')
        ->andWhere('u.user = :userObject')
        ->andWhere('u.type = :type')
        ->setParameter('status' , 1)
        ->setParameter('userObject' , $userObject)
        ->setParameter('type' , 2)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getSingleScalarResult();

    $balance = $credits - $debits;

    if (null == $balance)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    return $balance;

}
```

The other method I considered was to have a fixed account balance in the users table, which is worked out each time the user makes a transaction. My only reservation is that edge case with this gets out of sync.

Are there better methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify in **only one** query with the decode of the amount (sum or subtract I suppose), as follow:

```
public function getUserBalance(User $userObject)
{
    $qb = $this->transactionRepository->createQueryBuilder('u');

    $qb ->add('select','SUM(CASE WHEN u.type = 1 then u.amount ELSE -u.amount END)')
        ->where('u.status = :status')
        ->andWhere($qb->expr()->in('u.type', array(1,2)))
        ->andWhere('u.user = :userObject')
        ->setParameter('status' , 1)
        ->setParameter('userObject' , $userObject);

    $balance = $qb
        ->getQuery()
        ->getSingleScalarResult();

    return $balance;

}
```

Hope this help

Comment: Very nice suggestion! Thank you. Would you say, fine to work out balances from a transaction table on each call rather than having a fixed amount in the user table?

Comment: Hi @HappyCoder you are welcome! Depends on many factor, about how many times you need to display the related info, how many transaction an user can have etc. Generally a filed balance on the user table help a lot! Remember to update the value in the same transaction of the managed transaction and periodically check for disaligment between the transaction sum and the user balance field.